# Function of nltk.TaggerI in Steven Bird's book

Tags: python, nltk-book

I am currently going through Steven Bird's NLP with Python. I have a question. What is the function of nltk.TaggerI? It's in chapter 6, Example 6-5.

```
class ConsecutivePosTagger(nltk.TaggerI)
```

I hope to get a better idea about it. Thanks

Comment: You must show some effort and research before asking a question, including the package's own documentation. See [nltk.tag.api.TaggerI](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html?highlight=taggeri#nltk.tag.api.TaggerI)

Comment: Thank you Steve. However, I still learning around NLP and Python. Therefore, I still not clear its' function. I do understand that it can be used to tag() or teag_sents(). What I do not understand, will it cause a problem, if a class didn't defined a nltk.TaggerI and still work with tag() or tag_sents(). Thank you.

Comment: Your follow up question is as clear as mud. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)